# Cakephp: Cake is NOT able to connect to the database

Tags: cakephp

I have read on alot of threads here on stackoverflow and also other tutorials on the internet but can't get this to work!

I have just setup a cake project, (used it in the past v1.3.7), and everything passes besides the database connection, i get the error message: Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.

I have already gotten pdo_mysql up and running so i know thats not the problem.
And i also know that the user and password can connect to the database thru the given ip/socket that i have tried.

This is the config that im trying to use:

```
public $Phenomenon = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'cake',
    'password' => 'theCakePass',
    'database' => 'Phenomenon',
);
```

(Also tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost)

So my question is: How can i get more verbose error messages so i can find out whats wrong? Or simply how do i solve this?

System Specs:

```
Mac OS X 10.7
Apache/2.2.20
PHP 5.3.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting using vanilla PDO (not using cake); does that work?

And are you using Cake 2.0.5?

Comment: Thansk for the reply!

I you ment the vanilla PHP "forum" i just installed it and it works without a glitch. Took me about 2 min to set it up.

I am currently using Cake 2.0.4

Comment: Lol, upgraded to cake 2.0.5 and it worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, I meant vanilla, as in using the vanilla PDO functions, as listed in the PHP Manual. Glad it worked out, though.